# How to identify if user is inside or outside my network in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I have to identify if the acess is comming from my local network (the same network of my server) or is comming from the internet. (using ASP.NET)

I'm planning to create a extra security.. I mean, if the access is comming from outside, I will "allow" specifics users only.

I tried to search on the web but I found nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "the same network of my server" is highly subjective depending on your network layout. Is 10.50.0.84 the same network as 10.110.48.22? Will those IP addresses ever change? How does the flow from the internet come to your server (are reverse proxies in the mix? does external authentication exist?) These are just some of the questions that come to my mind. I think you need to talk to refine the requirements before throwing a solution together.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this (dummy code)

```
  private bool IsInSameSubnet(IPAddress address, IPAddress address2, IPAddress subnetMask) {
            bool isInSameSubnet = false;
            IPAddress network1 = GetNetworkAddress(address, subnetMask);
            IPAddress network2 = GetNetworkAddress(address2, subnetMask);
            if (network1 != null && network2 != null) {
                isInSameSubnet = network1.Equals(network2);
            }
            return isInSameSubnet;
        }
    private IPAddress GetNetworkAddress(IPAddress address, IPAddress subnetMask) {

        byte[] ipAdressBytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
        byte[] subnetMaskBytes = subnetMask.GetAddressBytes();

        if (ipAdressBytes.Length != subnetMaskBytes.Length)
            return null;
        //throw new ArgumentException("Lengths of IP address and subnet mask do not match.");

        byte[] broadcastAddress = new byte[ipAdressBytes.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < broadcastAddress.Length; i++) {
            broadcastAddress[i] = (byte)(ipAdressBytes[i] & (subnetMaskBytes[i]));
        }
        return new IPAddress(broadcastAddress);
    }
```

where `IsInSameSubnet` address checks if it is in the same network

example :

```
string computerIP = getIP();

            IPAddress ip1 = IPAddress.Parse(computerIP);
            IPAddress ip2 = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.0");
            IPAddress subnetMask = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.0.0");
```

and `getIp` method

```
 public static string getIP() {
            //if user behind proxy this should get it
            string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            if (ip != null && ip.Split(',').Count() > 1) {
                //if (ip.Split(',').Count() > 1)
                ip = ip.Split(',')[0];
            }

            //if user not behind proxy this should do it
            if (ip == null)
                ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            return ip;
        }
```